# Prevent user from seeing files

Tags: users

I need to give access to my server to a new user. This user will access one directory used for web server, in order to modify some files there. 
Now, I have created the user on the server, but when I try to log in with his username, I notice that I can see and download not only this users directory (which is a folder on the web-part of the files), but all files on all the other folders too.

Don't know if this is a permission issue on the oter files (wich the user should not have access to), or on this particular user. When creating the user, I made his homedirectory to be /var/www/xxxxx where xxxxx is the actual folder he should have access to.

To be a little clearer about the other folders he can see, they are located at /var/www/yyyy  All files in yyyy is visible for him and should be hidden.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What are the access permission flags of those other folder?

Answer (score 0):

Is the user connecting via ssh ? If so, there is a ChrootDirectory option to jail a user to a specified directory, meaning he can not navigate higher up the directory tree. Take a look here for a working example

https://www.debian-administration.org/article/590/OpenSSH_SFTP_chroot_with_ChrootDirectory

Comment: Hi, and thanks for showing me this link. It's not clear for me where to put the match rule described. Tried to place it in the ssh_configfile, but that had no effect. Any hint on this too?

Comment: Did you connect using the command sftp user@host ? The config goes in the sshd_config file.